# How can I record data when it is deleted?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, audit, hibernate-envers

I am currently using JPA Auditing, Envers for Spring Boot project.

I want to save the record when the data is deleted.

So I discovered @SQLDelete Annotation
But @SQLDelete Annotation doesn't apply to grammar written in JPQL

Is there a way to save the deletion history that is also applicable to JPQL grammar?

Comment: you can add this to properties file `spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete=true`

Comment: If i use spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete=true ,the data at the time I deleted is not registered, but the data just before is registered.